# efficiently writing to file

Tags: c++, optimization, io

would there be a more efficient way of writing to file than using fprintf in the bit of code below.  I'm doing this code for thousands of files and the bottle neck is the writing to file.  The file doesn't necessarily have to be readable by a human.  I had tried replacing my fprintf statements with sprintf statements and then doing one fprintf at the end to write the string to file.

```
string tmp_;
stringstream mom;
mom << path <<"/m" << j << ".mom";
tmp_ = mom.str();
FILE * mom_file;
mom_file = fopen(tmp_.c_str(),"w");

if (!mom_file)
{
   printf("Cannot open file '%s'\n", tmp_.c_str());
   exit(1);
}


int params_before=0; //the number of parameters in the vector before this atom due to other atoms
//we use this to keep track of where we are in the interpolation params vector

for(int k=0; k<Natoms; k++)
{
    string symbol = Monomers[j].GetAtom(k).GetSymbol();
    /*---------------------------MOMENTS--Rotation--and--Printing-----------------*/
    //perform rotations of the moments
    //Charge is invariant to rotation
    if(k==0)
    {
        fprintf(mom_file, "!  monomer properties from interpolation :)\n");
        fprintf(mom_file, "!  Basis %s\n",basis.c_str());
    }
    fprintf(mom_file, "\n%s%d          %4.10f    %4.10f    %4.10f    Rank  %d\n",symbol.c_str(),k+1,Monomers[j].GetAtom(k).GetLocalPosition(0),Monomers[j].GetAtom(k).GetLocalPosition(1),Monomers[j].GetAtom(k).GetLocalPosition(2),moments_rank[k]);
    fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(params_before));//print charge
    params_before += 1;//for charge
    if(moments_rank[k] >= 1) //Dipole
    {
        int tmp = params_before;
        interpolation_params.SetBlock(l_1_Wigner.MatrixTimesVector(interpolation_params.GetBlock(3,params_before)),params_before);
        params_before +=3;//add 3 to our location after we have rotated the dipole
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+1), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+2));//print the dipole
    }
    if(moments_rank[k] >= 2) //Quadrupole
    {
        int tmp = params_before;
        interpolation_params.SetBlock(l_2_Wigner.MatrixTimesVector(interpolation_params.GetBlock(5,params_before)),params_before);
        params_before +=5;//add 5 to our location after we have rotated the quadrupole
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+1), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+2), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+3), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+4));//print the Quadrupole
    }
    if(moments_rank[k] >= 3) //Octupole
    {
        int tmp = params_before;
        interpolation_params.SetBlock(l_3_Wigner.MatrixTimesVector(interpolation_params.GetBlock(7,params_before)),params_before);
        params_before +=7;//add 7 to our location after we have rotated the Octupole
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+1), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+2), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+3), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+4));
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp+5), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+6));//print the Octupole
    }
    if(moments_rank[k] == 4) //Hexadecapole
    {
        int tmp = params_before;
        interpolation_params.SetBlock(l_4_Wigner.MatrixTimesVector(interpolation_params.GetBlock(9,params_before)),params_before);
        params_before +=9;//add 9 to our location after we have rotated the Hexadecapole
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+1), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+2), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+3), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+4));
        fprintf(mom_file, "%15.12f %15.12f %15.12f %15.12f\n", interpolation_params.Element(tmp+5), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+6), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+7), interpolation_params.Element(tmp+8));//print the Hexadecapole
    }
    if(moments_rank[k] > 4 )
    {
        printf("oops monomer %d has moments of rank %d and the code can only handle rank 4\n",j,moments_rank[k]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
fclose(mom_file);
```

Comment: `the bottle neck is the writing to file` how have you profiled this?

Comment: this section of code is the formatting and writing part and is part of a much bigger function.  The time that the function runs is dramatically decreased if the writing part if commented out.

Comment: How do you know the code is responsible and not the actual IO itself?

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> The file doesn't necessarily have to be readable by a human

In that case, use binary format. Use `fwrite` to write the data and `fread` to read the data.

From my experience, you gain performance from couple of factors:

1. There is no need to do formatting conversions.
2. The size of file is smaller. The number of bytes that need to be transmitted to the disk and saved on the disk is less.

**Word of caution** (thanks @JerryCoffin):

When you do this, the data becomes less portable--for example, data written on a little-endian machine will need conversion to read it on a big-endian machine. As long as you're just saving and restoring data on the same machine, this is rarely an issue.

Comment: Good call (but probably also worth noting that when you do this, the data becomes less portable--for example, data written on a little-endian machine will need conversion to read it on a big-endian machine (but as long as you're just saving and restoring data on the same machine, this is rarely an issue).

Answer (score 0):

moments_rank[4] < 4, then you are exiting without closing the file . Apart from that , even if you are fstream and using write method instead of operator<< can be efficient as well. Try to benchmark and see.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilties - you'll need to make some actual measurements to see which applies:

1) the I/O is taking almost all the time, in which case check you can't get any improvement from a larger buffer ([`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf)); we can see you're not flushing anywhere unnecessary; potentially, think about tighter file formats and/or compression and/or a faster drive / RAID and/or writing fewer larger files if they're small enough to be inefficient (e.g. a few tens of kilobytes) and that would still suit their later use.

2) the code's taking almost all the time, in which case you could try distributing it across threads and/or using a binary format to reduce conversions

3) they're both significant, in which case try any combination of the above